# Naming Models vs. MonoBehaviours

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently ran into the problem where you can't instantiate `MonoBehaviour`s in unit tests, so I'm going through the process of moving all of my non Unity-related code (code which doesn't access any `MonoBehaviour` fields/methods) into separate model classes, which are then used in the corresponding `MonoBehaviour` class.  However, all of the Unity examples that I've seen have all the code associated with a given game object in a `MonoBehaviour` class.  For instance, an orc in the game has its code in an `Orc` class, which is derived from `MonoBehaviour`.  So I'm struggling with naming my classes when I separate the single `Orc` `MonoBehaviour` class into an orc model and an orc `MonoBehaviour`.  Is there a best practice guideline to follow when naming `MonoBehaviour` classes versus naming the corresponding model class?

Comment: I'd rather consider doing it right. Game programming is not like 'application programming'. Unit testing is -most of the time- a bit a silly. Here's a link to a similar question, with an answer explaining what and why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418845/is-unit-testing-viable-in-game-programming

Comment: That question seems to be mostly talking about how to write good tests for games.  My question is more about how to name my classes.  In my example above, I'd like to have an `Orc` class that I write tests against.  But the Unity books/examples that I've seen will have an "orc" script (derived from `MonoBehaviour`) attached to the orc in the scene.  I'm looking for a recommendation about how to name those `MonoBehaviour` scripts since the script will be an "orc" script, but `Orc` is already the name of the model class.

Comment: @Mark Unit test is nothing like silly, it allows to test method without running the project, with many different input and report a red flag when modifying a piece of code affect another (and many other things). Countless hours saved. This is actually a hiring case for us, an applicant claiming he does not perform tests for being useless coz it is Unity...well he better learn quick.

Comment: @BenRubin Naming convention is your call. Everyone (companies too) have their own. E.g. for AI I always name scripts AI_[whatItDoes], for example AI_Navigation, AI_PlayerInfoReceiver, etc. If it's an Orc and I code the "general orcish" behaviour" ("if femaleOrc do love else if male orc challenge or obey else kill"), I call it "AI_Orc". Class structuring and proper testing are on the link. Naming convention is your call, or you can google best practices, but for inspiration here's this one: http://dev.xeushack.com/top-10-unity-best-practices-naming-conventions-part-1/

Comment: If you are still lost and want a good answer, please describe your issue in details. I'm happy to help but from the information above I can BS only about "common best practices". Orc and orc-class on its own is very 'out of context'. Draw out the big picture, and give a few specific examples to the problems you face and the goal you have with your code as of testing.

Comment: All of this talk is pointless :)  In Unity there's a simple specific answer which Everts gave below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Games just like any other applications can run tests. If test was useless in games, Unity would not have spent hours developing a tool.

Just like any other applications, some parts cannot be tested like input that rely on the framework. In Unity, all the methods about the engine like Update, Collision and else cannot be tested but they can be faked.

Other case in Unity is MonoBehaviour but you can bypass that easily following that blog post:

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/07/28/unit-testing-at-the-speed-of-light-with-unity-test-tools/

Basically, the MB class gets all the Unity related actions and callbacks. The logic that needs to be tested goes in a custom class.

As for the naming you can use XXXXController (MB) and XXXContainer (non MB).

In your test, you focus on testing the XXXContainer that contains all the logic.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for.